# How to add Facebook interstitial ad in custom dialog?

Tags: java, ads, facebook-android-sdk, customdialog

In my app inside my main activity on back press i want to show a dialog with face book interstitial ads.

I created a custom dialog class to show my dialog whether user wants to exit or not on back press click listener, while the ad is shown to user in dialog.

For this custom dialog i want the Facebook interstitial ad to appear but not getting the result, only dialog with buttons appear with no loaded ad?

How to load Facebook interstitial ads in dialog?

This is dialog layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/facebook_interestial_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/facebook_interestial_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Are you sure to exit app ?"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yes_exit_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="YES" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/no_exit_btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:text="NO" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is View Dialog class

```
    import com.facebook.ads.AbstractAdListener;
import com.facebook.ads.Ad;

public class ViewDialog {

    com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd interstitial;
    Ad adfacebook;
        public void showDialog(Activity activity) {
            Context c1= activity.getBaseContext();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.fbdialogexit);


            LinearLayout adlayout = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.facebook_interestial_ad);



            interstitial = new com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd(c1, "your id");
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AbstractAdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                adfacebook = ad;


            }
        });
        interstitial.loadAd();

            Button dialogExitCancelButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.no_exit_btn);
            dialogExitCancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            Button dialogExitButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yes_exit_btn);
            dialogExitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();

        }


}
```

Calling in main activity back press button

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() { ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
    alert.showDialog(StartActivity.this);

}
```